# Basic configuration of Nginx with django on EC2:

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, django

I want to configure my dockerized django app with nginx and run it on an EC2 instance and I can't get it to work. I am a beginner with nginx.

My error when I do `docker-compose -f production.yml up` is:

> > client sent invalid method while reading client request line, client: 80.153.184.19, server: ec2-XXXXX.eu-central-2.compute.amazonaws.com, request: "�U�F'��Io�q�+!�P��

And I'm like whuat? Isn't there any basic config for this to make it run smoothly?

My nginx config myconf:

```
server {

    set $my_host $host;
    if ($host ~ "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+") {
        set $my_host "ec2-XXXXX.eu-central-2.compute.amazonaws.com";
    }

    listen 80;
    server_name ec2-XXXXX.eu-central-2.compute.amazonaws.com;
    charset utf-8;
    error_log /dev/stdout info;
    access_log /dev/stdout;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $my_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

#volumes:
#  production_caddy: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: heatbeat_website_production_django
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    command: /start

  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - django

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0
```

my dockerfile for nginx:

```
FROM tutum/nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY ./compose/production/nginx/myconf.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

I am extremely grateful for any help... I'm so stuck... Thanks in advance!

Comment: no one has an idea?

Comment: Seems you have ssl redirection enabled but don't listen in the nginx configuration

Comment: Thank you Federico! Sorry could you elaborate? Where do you think I have ssl enabled and how could I make nginx listen?

Comment: that depends of the context, if your application force a secure access over ssl you need enable it in nginx config, eg:  https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71. In another case you can disable the https access restriction in your application.

Comment: thanks again! Well at the end I need ssl. But for now it would be enough to have it work only with http. I am using a cookiecutter django project. But in my settings I actually have the config: ```SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT``` set to false... Are you sure that this is the problem? But maybe another setting overwrites it...

Comment: Ok I’m not expert in django but check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571361/django-cookie-cutter-ssl and test if my theory is correct

Comment: I tried this and still get the same error. Yet, I still think it could be an issue with ssl since my browser also shows me a ```ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR``` ... I'm clueless... I also tried to follow tutorial in the link you posted, but can't validate my domain with let's encrypt.... maybe it's also my nginx config that's not correct?

Comment: Even more confusing: Built an dummy app to test. Also cookiecutter. Same nginx config, sam ec2 instance, **same error locally**, but on the ec2 instance the test app works.... so confused....

Comment: only difference is that my app I want to deploy has an RDS database connected

Answer (score 0):

I am curious about this section:

```
    set $my_host $host;
    if ($host ~ "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+") {
        set $my_host "ec2-XXXXX.eu-central-2.compute.amazonaws.com";
    }
```

I see exceptions like this in my application logging:

```
django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '54.148.178.171'...
```

When I do a reverse proxy I see that the IP is inside AWS. But I cannot identify the resource. I see that you are using a canonical server name and rewriting the IP to it, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of ALLOWED_HOSTS?

---

Okay, I figured out why your solution made me uncomfortable. You are taking any IP address and mapping it. The typical problem is to capture the ELB's IP address that changes over time. So it's much safer to put that in a location block. In the example below I have 'aws.elb.com' in my ALLOWED_HOSTS list and on the ELP Health Check tab I specified my ping target as ELB-health-check. This should be a more secure approach.

```
    location /ELB-health-check {
        set $my_host $host;
        if ($host ~ "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+") {
          set $my_host "aws.elb.com";
        }
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # set $my_host "aws.elb.com";
        proxy_set_header Host $my_host;
        # now send the request to the app
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
     }
```